# Get the type of the generic interface in Java after serialization

Tags: java, generics, serialization

I was tinkering around with some Java code, and I found a piece of code, that I wrote some years ago for pre-generic-type Java.

Basicly it is a set of interfaces, where the base interface is something like that:

```
public interface RandomInterface
{
  void setter(Object o);
  Object getter();
}
```

And there are several other interfaces, extending this interface, and assigning specific type to the parameter and return type:

```
public interface AnotherRandomInterface extends RandomInterface
{
  void setter(String s);
  String getter();
}
```

I was wondering if I could use one interface instead of the "design hell" described above, in the following fashion:

```
public interface GenericInterface<T>
{
  void setter(T o);
  T getter();
}
```

This is valid and legal in Java, but the object(s) implementing this interface are getting serialized and sent to another java application over the network.

The problem is, that the application receiving the object has "no clue" about the type of the object's payload, because it was defined as generic in the interface. Is there any way to extract this information after deserialization?
If not, is there any way to store it in the object itself before serialization - then retrieving it with a method defined in another interface?

Comment: If you know its type, just cast it.

Comment: Yes, use the generic interface by all means.  Yes, yes.  Java is statically typed.  On the deserializing end if the compiler is happy, then the cast will be done for you.  If there is a warning *and* you can convince yourself that the object is type safe ... then just cast it yourself and suppress the warning.  There really is very little difference in what is happening between using the generified and non-generified interfaces, btw.  The main one is that the compiler tries to help you maintain type safeness.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I don't know the type, because there is more than one object implementing the interface, with different types, and the "parsing" of all incoming objects are done by one object.

Comment: @estol: Most of the time you actually do know the type.  Java is statically typed so you're always serializing a generic object with a concrete type.  Similarly, on the receiving end, it is most usual to be expecting a concrete object.  How often do you ever serialize an object whose type you can't predict and then send it to another computer?  TL;DR: Mostly, when you use `GenericInterface<MyType>` on the serialiaing end, you're using the same interface on the the receiving end that is also expecting a `GenericInterface<MyTYpe>`.

Comment: @scottb on the receiving end I truly don't know the type, as there are different classes, using different type of variable to transfer data. Of course, I could guess by the number of objects recieved, but that could fail easily. So the best I could do is to expect a GenericInterface<?> type - I'm not sure if the diamond questionmark is correct there. Then there is the added problem, of the return type of the getter. Maybe I don't understand you correctly, in that case sorry for my stupidity.

Comment: @scottb just tried it. I understand now what you meant. Giant facepalm on my end. The variable returned by the getter is an instance of the type defined in the generic, still it would be nice if I didn't have to "probe" the variable with all those instanceof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java, generics are implemented using "type erasure". That means that at runtime, including serialization/deserialization the actual value of the generic parameter `T` is not available. So no, you cannot tell which version of this interface was used.

Perhaps if the concrete class that implements this interface contains an actual object of type `T`, then you could use that to figure out what `T` is after you deserialize it.